# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when using setState inside function()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to convert an arrow function into a function. This is due to a problem with Slick Slider, as it [does not support properly arrow functions](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/841).

I have convert this:

```
beforeChange={(current, next) => this.setState({slideIndex: next})}
```

Into this:

```
beforeChange={function(current, next) {
  this.setState({slideIndex: next});
}}
```

But does not work. Already tried this solution:

```
beforeChange={function(current, next) {
    this.setState(function() {
        return {slideIndex: next};
    });
}}
```

Comment: because `this` scope is wrong. When using arrow function (`=>`) `this` remains, but when using `function(){}`, `this` has it's own scope, so `this.setState()` will not work, unless you bind the function with `...}.bind(this)`

Comment: _"This is due to a problem with Slick Slider..."_ - No, IE and its missing support is the problem, not Slick Slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bind` for passing the context to the function:

```
beforeChange={function(current, next) {
  this.setState({slideIndex: next});
}.bind(this)}
```

This will pass `this` to the function so that when referencing `this` inside the function will be the one passed through `bind`.

Arrow functions do this automatically, they pass the context of where they're being called to the function itself, so by removing the arrow function you removed the correct context.

Other functions that will allow you to manually pass the context are: [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and the aforementioned [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).